# JQuery slice() or each() for performance?

Tags: jquery, performance, each, slice

```
$('.row').slice(0, 3).css('background-color: green');
$('.row').slice(4, 6).css('background-color: yellow');
$('.row').slice(6, 10).css('background-color: green');
```

Or

```
x = 0;
$('.row').each(function() {
   if (x >= 0 && x <= 3) {
      $(this).css('background-color: green');
   }
   if (x >= 4 && x <= 6) {
      $(this).css('background-color: yellow');
   }
   if (x >= 6 && x <= 10) {
      $(this).css('background-color: green');
   }
   x++;
});
```

Is one faster than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slice. Each does comparisons on every iteration. Slice will just take the columns. Plus slice expresses the intention better - this will allow for better optimization (if any) and code is a lot more readable.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I'm not convinced: http://jsperf.com/10543111/2 - to be fair, you simply c-p'd the questioner's errors.

Comment: @Carl if you're optimizing it, then optimize both cases, not one: http://jsperf.com/10543111/3 ;) Slice is almost twice faster. The two additional DOM queries was the reason that slowed the first test case down.

Comment: @valentinas that doesn't do what you think it does.  look at the first test output.  the later DOM elements aren't colored.  I revised mine to have a single dom query, each still comes out on top.  I also tried coloring everything, then slicing just the yellow.

Comment: I should also point out that I agree with your answer - because slice expresses intent better - but it's not strictly answering the question.

Comment: @Carl weird - try this: http://jsperf.com/10543111/3 it's the same as your version but for some reason first case is faster. what do you think?

Comment: I selected on `div.row` instead of `.row`; apparently including the element type slows down the jQ.  I also get that `.row` performs better (unexpectedly to me).  With both versions close to something optimal, however, the difference is marginal.  Fortunately, I can stand by my assertion that `slice` is more readable either way ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using exactly your example and mainly considering performance a pure css solution is probably even faster:

```
.row:nth-child(-n+10) { background-color: green; }
.row:nth-child(-n+6)  { background-color: yellow; }
.row:nth-child(-n+3)  { background-color: green; }
```

The order looks reversed, but what it does is: first all 10 items in the top 10 will be made green, then the top 6 yellow, then the top 3 green again.

But this works only on static html. If you are changing the selection dynamically then indeed use jquery.slice.